# Unity3D Sprite ... but single sided?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-2dtools

Unity's excellent `Sprite`s ([Unity's excellent new sprites](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.html)), among other worthy advantages, are in fact double-sided.

In a 2D or 3D use case, you can flip the little bastards around and still see them from behind - they are rendered from both sides.

I also love the unlit shader used on them (ie, Sprite-Default, not Sprite-Diffuse).

However, I have need for an old-fashioned single-sided `Sprite`.

Fortunately, you can freely download the source of the excellent shader used by Unity ... confusingly, you can't just open it in the Editor, but see [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/builtin-unity-shaders-source.2085/) and thence [here](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive).

After **considerable sustained effort involving inexpensive whisky**, I made two (2) modifications to the shader.

1. I changed the name in the first line of the file to "DefaultSingle" rather than "Default"
2. I commented away the line `Cull Off`

(I then made a new `Material`, called it "Sprite Single Sided", set the shader to this new one, and on `Sprite`s I replace the material slot with that new material.)

in fact, have I screwed-up anything in the shader by making this modification?   Can one gaily comment out "Cull off" without causing further problems? Is there some gotchya in changing that usual material used by `Sprite` (you can't "see" it so I don't know). More broadly, is there a more correct way to achieve single-sided `Sprite`?

```
// file "Sprites-DefaultSingle.shader"
Shader "Sprites/DefaultSingle"
{
  Properties
  {
    [PerRendererData] _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    [MaterialToggle] PixelSnap ("Pixel snap", Float) = 0
  }

  SubShader
  {
    Tags
    { 
      "Queue"="Transparent" 
      "IgnoreProjector"="True" 
      "RenderType"="Transparent" 
      "PreviewType"="Plane"
      "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="True"
    }

  ///  Cull Off
    Lighting Off
    ZWrite Off
    Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha

    Pass
    {
    CGPROGRAM
      #pragma vertex vert
      #pragma fragment frag
      #pragma multi_compile _ PIXELSNAP_ON
      #pragma shader_feature ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
      #include "UnityCG.cginc"
      
      struct appdata_t
      {
        float4 vertex   : POSITION;
        float4 color    : COLOR;
        float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
      };

      struct v2f
      {
        float4 vertex   : SV_POSITION;
        fixed4 color    : COLOR;
        float2 texcoord  : TEXCOORD0;
      };
      
      fixed4 _Color;

      v2f vert(appdata_t IN)
      {
        v2f OUT;
        OUT.vertex = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, IN.vertex);
        OUT.texcoord = IN.texcoord;
        OUT.color = IN.color * _Color;
        #ifdef PIXELSNAP_ON
        OUT.vertex = UnityPixelSnap (OUT.vertex);
        #endif

        return OUT;
      }

      sampler2D _MainTex;
      sampler2D _AlphaTex;

      fixed4 SampleSpriteTexture (float2 uv)
      {
        fixed4 color = tex2D (_MainTex, uv);

#if ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA
        // get the color from an external texture ..
        color.a = tex2D (_AlphaTex, uv).r;
#endif //ETC1_EXTERNAL_ALPHA

        return color;
      }

      fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
      {
        fixed4 c = SampleSpriteTexture (IN.texcoord) * IN.color;
        c.rgb *= c.a;
        return c;
      }
    ENDCG
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "can flip the little bastards around and still see them from behind" lol ...sadly I don't know anything about shaders. Not my thing.

Comment: Years later, I needed this and found it here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That won't cause any problems and is the correct way of doing things. If you want to be really explicit about it you could change the line to `Cull Back` instead of commenting it out, but back-face culling is defined as the default behaviour so just removing it is fine.

Comment: AHHHH!  great info.  that would explain why `Cull On` didn't work.  Very nice, thanks

Comment: Sprite's shader code changed since the original question was asked. The current version can be downloaded here (expand Downloads dropdown): https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, neither of these changes have any effects other than the that which you intended. Also, this is the most correct way to achieve this- it's the only thing Cull is for.