# Using a quad instead of a sprite for 2d textures that only have 1 side visible during gameplay?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am creating a 2d game in unity and I am using hundreds of sprite game objects to represent my terrain.

However, the thing is, I only ever see 1 side of a texture during gameplay, but I am rendering both sides when using sprites.

Side that player sees:

[image]

Another side that renders, but player won't ever see it:

[image]

So my question is: Should I use quads and texture only 1 side instead?

Comment: Back faces are culled during rendering. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Could you provide some documentation that says so? I would love to read about it more.

Comment: Its just how the shader works with sprites and rendering. Sprites tell the system that it should be drawn regardless of its orientation, but the side "away" from the camera is never actually drawn (this happens at the OpenGL level or possibly lower, as because it faces away from the camera no time is spent drawing it). If you want it to not render the backside in the editor, you can use a custom shader (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36205501/1663383)).